# Useing Router out of IOC container Laravel

Tags: laravel-4

I have a interface

```
 <?php namespace Acme\Billing;

  use Stripe;

  class StripeBilling implements BillingInterface {

  }
```

But i want to use return Redirect::refresh(); but I'm getting the following error:

Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException

Class 'Acme\Billing\Redirect' not found

So i know I will has to do something like use Illuminate\Routing; but this isn't working and allowing me to use the redirect method.

So how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$redirector = \App::make('redirect');
return $redirector->to('url');
```

Or use it directly like:

```
return \App::make('redirect')->to('url');
```

Or any methods you want but `refresh()` method may produce a redirect loop in the same page, so be careful about it.

**Update:** Also remember, when using another class with namespace from another namespace then use a preceding `\`, i.e. `\Acme\Billing\Redirect`, if you use a `use SomeNameSpace\XXX;` without `\` from `Acme\Billing` then composer will think it's `Acme\Billing\SomeNameSpace\XXX`.

Comment: I can use that within the interface as it's outside the IoC container